# update specific field in meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I want to update only the name field, the problem with the code I have is that if I update a document, all the mongo documents are updated.

As I update a document in specific, I must admit that I am new to this mongo so any help I thank you.

**Client**

updatename.html

```
<template name="updatename">
        <form class="editor-container">

          <input class=“save” type="text" id="card" value=“{{name}}”>

          <button type="button" class=“save” id="save">save</button>

        </form>
</template>
```

updatename.js

```
Template.updatename.events({
  'click .save’: function (e, t) {
       e.preventDefault();

       FlowRouter.watchPathChange();
       var name = FlowRouter.current().params._id;

       var name = $('#card').val();


       Meteor.call('name.update',name);
       FlowRouter.go('/');
   }
});
```

**Server**

name.js

```
Meteor.methods({
  'name.update'( name) {

    Name.update({
        Name.update({},{ $set: { nam: name }},{multi:true})
    });
}
});
```

Comment: is `name` field `nam` in update command???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend few improvisations over your Meteor code.

1. Atleast use Title Case/ CamelCase for better readability of the template name and Meteor Methods for other developer.
2. use `submit .formClassName` instead of using `click .save`, also specifiy parameter name with sincerity like `function (event, template)`
3. When you updating document for logged user and not other user, as **dmayo** mentioned in the code use `Name.update({_id: Meteor.userId()},{ $set: {nam: name}})`, but there is no sense of specifying `{ multi: true }` when you know that there is going to be only 1 record when you are updating. You can use `{ multi: true }` when you desire to impact many records based on criteria that are definitely going to return more than 1 record.
4. use `check(name, String)` in `Meteor.method` call to ensure what you are sending to the server is eligible for further operations.
5. Use [aldeed autoforms](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform) when you know there is no out of the box implementation and is going to be simple.

   Below is the improvised code for better readability and up to standards

> **Client**

**update-name.html**

```
<template name="UpdateName">

        <form class="editorContainerForm">
            <input type="text" id="card" value=“{{name}}”>
            <button type="submit">Save</button>
        </form>

</template>
```

**update-name.js**

```
Template.UpdateName.events({
  'submit .editorContainerForm’: function (event, template) {
       event.preventDefault();   

       FlowRouter.watchPathChange();
       var name = FlowRouter.current().params._id;
       var name = $('#card').val();

       Meteor.call('updateName',name, function(error, response){
        if(error){
            // Show some BERT ERROR message for better user experience
            // use "meteor add themeteorchef:bert" to add package
        } else {
            // Show some BERT SUCCESS message for better user experience
        });
       FlowRouter.go('/');
   }
});
```

> **Server**

**name.js**

```
Meteor.methods({
  updateName( name ) {
    check(name, String);
    Name.update({ _id: Meteor.userId },{ $set: { name: name }});
    // Use below code only if you know there can be multiple records for same ID
    // Name.update({ _id: Meteor.userId },{ $set: { name: name }}, { multi: true });
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `name.js` file (on the server) your mongo query is empty, so when mongo queries your database, it matches all of the  documents/records.

```
Name.update(query, changes, options)
```

That is the format per the mongo docs. You need to have a unique identifier. Your form is saving a "name", and that's what you are passing to the Meteor.method, but you're not telling the method who's changing their name. If the user is logged in, then you can just use the meteor unique id `Meteor.userId()`

```
Name.update({_id: Meteor.userId()},{ $set: {nam: name}},{multi:true})
```

Also, your option `multi:true` says to update any and all documents that match the query. If in your original method as written, you had `multi:false` (the default) then only one document would have been updated (but probably not the one you wanted as the first match would have been updated because of your empty query field.

Mongo docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/
Metor docs: https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-update